# why can see right files after git checkout -b $local_branch based on git checkout remotes/origin/remote_branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

What I did is

1. `git fetch` to get all remote branch meta data,
2. `git checkout remotes/origin/$remote_branch`
3. `git checkout -b $local_branch`

When I brow files in Intellij, all files on remote branch show correctly.
Which did the magic to pull the remote files?

Comment: Please avoid using your personal aliases at SO. [edit] and fix `git co` -> `git checkout`

Answer (score 1):

Which did the magic to pull the remote files?

Your second checkout did create a local branch based on your current HEAD, which was origin/$remote_branch.

But the right command would be to use the new command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) ([presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

```
git switch -c $local_branch origin/$remote_branch
```

Comment: if a local branch is created, shouldn't it be seen with `git branch -l`?

Comment: @yk42b I prefer `git branch -avv` to be sure to see everything.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting from a bad assumption: `git fetch` does not merely get *metadata*, it gets *commits*.  The commits contain both data—snapshots of files—and metadata: information about who made the commit, when, and so on.  Having obtained any new commits required, your `git fetch` then goes on to update your *remote-tracking names*, which are the `origin/*` names.  Their full names are `refs/remotes/origin/name`, where each *`name`* corresponds to a branch name as seen in the other Git, over at `origin`.

When you run `git checkout remotes/origin/branch`, your Git puts you in *detached HEAD* mode with that one specific commit checked out.  So this step updated the files you can see in your working tree.  The `git checkout -b name` step created a new *name* that identifies this same commit—the same commit that `refs/remotes/origin/branch` identifies—and no files need updating.

It's the *commits* that matter.  The names, whether they are remote-tracking names like `origin/somebranch` or (local) branch names like `somebranch`, merely help you (and Git) *find* the commits.  The commits contain the files, and *are* the history.  The `git fetch` step obtains, from some other Git repository, any new commits that they have, that you don't, that you need; from then on, everything you do here is local.